# How do I fill the hole caused by removing a door plate on a metal door jamb?

Tags: doors, trim, interior, metal, jamb

I recently got new doors and need to move the door plate on a metal door jamb. I was hoping someone had the know how on how to fill the hole that will now be on the door jamb from where the previous door plate was.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to attach a cover plate.

Answer (score 1):

For filling holes on the **jamb**, I have had the most success using a two-part wood filler (similar to automotive body filler). Slightly overfill the old hole and let it set, then plane it down with a Surform plane ("cheese grater" plane) until level. Coarse then fine sand until smooth, prime, and paint to match. You will not be able to tell there was ever a hole there, and you can screw right into it just like wood if the new strike plate holes overlap into the area.